# Using a MAX6675 with Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, pi-3, spi

I have played with the raspberry pi 3 for a short while now. I bought a MAX6675 Chip to read the temperature on a supported k-type thermocouple. I have tried time and time again over the past three days and im fed up with it. (I am very new to python and using the raspberry pi GPIO)  So here is what I have done and tried.

### ___________________________________________

First off here are the pictures of the wiring setup and the **exact** chip i'm using.

[The Wiring is Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDyLR.jpg)

[The MAX6675 Chip is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzGEk.jpg)

I have tried to Use, install, and run [this github page](https://github.com/keiichishima/RPiSensors) as a python module/library.

### ___________________________

I may not be installing this page right also,
to install I type in the term.

```
sudo pip install git+git//github.com/keiichishima/RPiSensors
```

As a side note I have also tried to use a [max31855 library](https://github.com/Tuckie/max31855) that claims to also support the max6675. The only issue is once is it ran, i Only get

```
tc: 32.0 and rj: 32.0
```

So it obviously dosent see or work in this configuration.

I want to get this working, as well as help anyone else that happens to view this thread so if you know what you are doing... just ignore my mistakes and direct me in the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [Python script to read the MAX6675](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_MAX6675_py).

You need to edit the script to define the SPI set-up you are using from one of the following.

- pi.spi_open(0, 1000000, 0)   # CE0, 1Mbps, main SPI
- pi.spi_open(1, 1000000, 0)   # CE1, 1Mbps, main SPI
- pi.spi_open(0, 1000000, 256) # CE0, 1Mbps, auxiliary SPI
- pi.spi_open(1, 1000000, 256) # CE1, 1Mbps, auxiliary SPI
- pi.spi_open(2, 1000000, 256) # CE2, 1Mbps, auxiliary SPI

It requires the pigpio daemon to be running (`sudo pigpiod`).

Comment: Two Things, how do i know which type of spi-setup is necessary and also once one is decided on how do i "daisy-chain" or wire two MAX6675's together.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed the pigpio and ran it (with the daemon running) It is only reading 0.00 values? Any ideas?

Comment: Alright, I have CLK = 23, CS = 24, DO = 21. I am still getting 0.00 as a output. I have tried to go to raspi-config and enable spi by default. It is not there as usual. So I uncommented it in config.txt. Maby I'm missing something else?

Comment: I have to be missing something... Prior to your last comment I had my 3 wires connected to _physical_ pins, 21, 23 and 24. 21 is MISO... 23 CLK.... and 24 is CE0. If i connect it to BCM pins 21 23 and 24, pins 23 an 24 are not apart with hardware SPI which i believe your using. I dont want to waste your time, but this is just not working...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55653/discussion-between-tylertotally-and-joan).

Comment: I thought this ought to be moved to chat because of it not working yet, also I was prompted. Here is my wiring so far, i.imgur.com/YTfF8Qg.png
Please excuse the crudeness / low quality of it. I eventually will have two of these sensors working in unison. Because of the time it took me, I decided to get one working, then wire the two (which I hope will be easier).

Comment: I have Swapped the two wires accordingly. I am **still** getting "0.00" as the temperature. Recap, I have is wired correctly as you have said. I have the daemon running. And I replaced the sensor. I have uncommented the first string (pi.spi_open(0, 1000000, 0) # CE0, 1Mbps, main SPI). I dont know what else to do. I am running raspbian PIXEL. I may have to enable spi? but i dont know ... what do you think?

Comment: Should i swap them and try again? Just in case?

Comment: we are sure cluttering up the thread. I have swapped them and it didnt do anything. Just as a update.

Comment: If you can see if [piscope](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) shows any activity.  We can delete all useless comments.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the ultimate dead thread resurrection, but your pinout is wrong. I've corrected it here. SPI0 uses pins 24 and 26 for Chip Select. I haven't tested yet but you could jump DO and CLK between 2 chips with one CS on 24 and the other CS on 26.[image]